# Is it possble to set a PostgreSQL schema and table name as a variable in Mapserver?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mapserver

In Mapserver it is possible to set a variable when connecting to postGIS. This way I have created an fill-in form where you can enter a postcode and then you get a result.

How can do this with putting a runtime variable in the Mapserver. Like this:

```
DATA "geom from (select t1.geom from schemaname.tablename t1 where t1.code = '%code%') as selectie using unique code using srid=28992"
```

In the html / openlayers script you can refer to what is between the % %.

Now I want to make a selection tool for querying a different schema and table. So you have an input where you fill in a schemaname and tablename and then you get a result from that table.

I thought that it would be something like this:

```
DATA "geom from (select t1.geom, from %schemaname%.%tablename%) as selectie using unique code using srid=28992"
```

Unfortunately this is not working. Does someone know whether this is possible and how I can make this work.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it not possible with MapServer.

I would try I different approach, using the [WMS GetFeatureInfo request](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcims/9.3/general/mergedprojects/wms_connect/wms_connector/get_featureinfo.htm), which is intended for information retrieving like the one you mention at the beginning of your question.

MapServer implements this request. On client side, OpenLayers has a [control, also named GetFeatureInfo](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-control.html), that makes easier using this request.

Comment: Thanks! Too bad it is not possible. Do you know how I can make it work with the GetFeatureInfo request? What I want is not retrieving information, but I want to show a map.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with Mapserver version 6.0.3.

You need to add a validation in the layer-part. Like this:

```
VALIDATION # for validation of runtime substitution
        'maand' '^[0-9]{6}$'
        'tabelnaam' '^[a-zA-Z\-_]+$'
END
```

Then the runtime substitution is working in the data parameter

```
DATA "geom from (select * from %month%.%tablename%) as selection using unique gid using srid=28922"
```